# Linq for entities Framework 4.1 tutorials/ebooks links

Tags: linq-to-entities, entity-framework-4.1

Is there any good LINQ tutorial for Entities Framework 4.1 Code First for medium to complex level? Please suggest books as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Linq-to-entities you can check MSDN:

- [Syntax examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896265.aspx)
- [Linq-to-entities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386964.aspx)

Sources for EFv4.1 code first are:

- [ADO.NET team blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/)
- [Morteza Manavi's blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/default.aspx)
- [Julia Lerman's blog](http://thedatafarm.com/blog/)
- [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/entity-framework-4.1)

As I know there is no book covering EFv4.1 yet.

Edit (May 2012): There are two books about EFv4.2 (Code first / DbContext API) now:

- [Programming EF Code First](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449312942)
- [Programming EF DbContext](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449312969)

Answer (score 0):

Just follow the [ADO.NET](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/) blog. I've learnt so much from those articles/series!