# An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same key

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4.1

I have seen the related question here:

[An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6033638/an-object-with-the-same-key-already-exists-in-the-objectstatemanager-the-object)

But, I have not already loaded my entity (UserView.Employee) from the context anywhere, as you can see in the code snippet below.

```
public ActionResult EditEmployee(UserViewDetailsModel UserView)
        {
            UserView.Employee.Contact = db.Contacts.Find(UserView.Employee.Contact.ContactID);
            UserView.Employee.Manager = db.Employees.Find(UserView.ManagerID);
            db.Entry(UserView.Employee).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

Please tell me, how can I save the changes in this case ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have VS to hand to test this out but can you try something like:

```
db.Entry(UserView.Employee).CurrentValues.SetValues(EntityState.Modified);
```