# Why I do I fall into all of the hurdles for a simple update in EF?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.3

I have an ID with me and I have name with me. So in essence, my method just has these parameters:

```
public void Foo(int id, string name)
{
}
```

and I have this piece of logic inside method:

```
User user = new User(){ Id = id, Name = name };
Db.Entry(user).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
Db.SaveChanges();
```

That's it. Nothing fancy. I get this error: `"An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same key"`

and this answer by Ladislav Mrnka: [An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6033638/an-object-with-the-same-key-already-exists-in-the-objectstatemanager-the-object)

suggests to use `context.Entry(oldEntity).CurrentValues.SetValues(newEntity);` but I don't really have oldEntity with me. Can anybody just please tell me how do I update just 1 property of User? I am getting nuts.

Comment: why not updateing using the select from entity instead of doing System.Data.EntityState.Modified;

Comment: I don't have code-first experience (and thus won't post an answer), but is `Db` above referring to a database context? If so, contexts in the model-first and database-first worlds are designed to be short-lived objects based on the unit-of-work pattern. Why not create a new context to perform this operation?

Comment: @COLD TOLD: Because I want it to be efficient. I don't want to fire 2 requests just for the sake of updating a single property of few tens of properties that I have in my User Model.

Comment: @AdamRobinson: Thanks. But that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Can you post more Code? The posted Code is ok.

Comment: @LuckStrike: That is the only piece of code. There is nothing more to post :). Just consider Db as instance of DbContext and that's about it. I don't think posting my User model here is required.

Comment: @Jack: You don't show where you're creating `Db`.

Comment: @Adam: I only create once per request, once created I store it inside HttpContext.Items. Hence even though I make multiple request to DB, it uses same DbContext. Does that help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I only create once per request, once created I store it inside
>   HttpContext.Items. Hence even though I make multiple request to DB, it
>   uses same DbContext. Does that help?

If any of that "multiple requests to DB" loads user with the same ID you will get this exception. Try to use this:

```
public void Foo(int id, string name) {
   var user = Db.Users.Local.SingleOrDefault(u => u.Id == id);
   if (user == null) {
      user = new User { Id = id };
      Db.Users.Attach(user);
   } 

   user.Name = name;
   Db.SaveChanges();
}
```

The code first try to get user instance from already loaded entities (no query to database) and creates a new instance only if the user was not loaded yet.

Comment: Won't this only update the user if you create and attach that stub entity?  If you have an existing user, you're not marking it as modified.

Comment: @JohnH: It makes changes to attached user so you should not need to change its state - EF should detect the change.

Comment: So it does!  I always assumed we had to do it for everything unless we specifically attached an entity.  Thanks.

Comment: Ladislav Mrnka to the rescue again!

Comment: @Ladislav: Is that required for delete as well? In short, is it required to that everytime? The "Local"?

Comment: @Jack: Yes. You can never have two entity instances with the same key attached to the same context instance.