# Object with same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a view in my EF that I receive my data from to insert into a table. The table only have  ID that is the primary key. It will insert the first record but as soon as I add the second one I get this error:

An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. The existing object is in the Modified state. An object can only be added to the ObjectStateManager again if it is in the added state.

I have google for answers but it does not seem to help for what I am trying to achieve here.

Code:

```
var AllTraininOffices = dbIMIS.View_TrainingOffices;

foreach (var office in AllTraininOffices)
{ 
   discounts.EntityNo = office.ID;
   discounts.EntityType = 0;
   discounts.Discount = Discount;
   discounts.DiscountReason = discount.DiscountReason;
   discounts.DiscountAmount = DiscountAmount;
   discounts.CreatedOn = DateTime.Now;
   discounts.CreatedBy = userData.SaicaId;
   discounts.UpdatedBy = userData.SaicaId;
   discounts.UpdatedOn = DateTime.Now;
   discounts.ProductDescription = discount.ProductDescription;
   discounts.ExpiryDate = Convert.ToDateTime(discount.ExpiryDate);
   discounts.FeeCategoryId = GetFeeCategoryID(discount.FeeCategory);
   discounts.DiscountStatus = true;

   db.AddToDiscounts(discounts);

   db.SaveChanges();

}
```

Comment: Can you insert a breakpoint at the db.AddToDiscounts(discounts); line and check the value of the Id property of your discounts object? Could it be that SQL Server isn't configured to create a new primary key value for you so the first one is 0 and the second one collides?

Comment: Yes the first item's id value is 0 and the after that the id value is the last id in the SQL table. How can I fix this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6033638/an-object-with-the-same-key-already-exists-in-the-objectstatemanager-the-object)

Comment: I found the mistake I have made. I have created an instance only once of my Discount Object. I have move it inside my loop now it works fine. Thanks for the assistance.