# Why ModelState manager does not let me delete a record?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

first of all happy new year to all !!!!

i have following code to remove a record from the db table `tr_shoppingCart`

```
 tr_ShoppingCart cart = new tr_ShoppingCart
                        {
                            cartId = sc.CartId,
                            CartGenDt = sc.CreateTime,
                            UserId = ((SessionData)Session["object"]).sessObj.UserId,
                            prodId = obj.prodId,
                            Qnty = obj.Qnty,
                            Total = obj.Total
                        };


                        if (ModelState.IsValid)
                        {
                            //db.Entry(cart).State = System.Data.EntityState.Deleted;
                            db.tr_ShoppingCart.Attach(cart);
                            db.tr_ShoppingCart.Remove(cart);
                            db.SaveChanges();
                        }
```

but it has given the error:

> An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager.
>   The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same
>   key.

[image]

here is my DB table tr_ShoppingCart

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This question is explained in more detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6033638/an-object-with-the-same-key-already-exists-in-the-objectstatemanager-the-object). I assume that `cartId` is your key. Check that sc.CartId is not already in tr_ShoppingCart list. If it is, than you must ensure that you generate your ids correctly.

Comment: in the db tables tr_ShoppingCart cartId and ProdId was set as PKs where CartID is a GUID generated in the client.

Comment: Try this before attaching: var theCart = db.tr_ShoppingCart.Where(c => c.cartId == sc.CartId && c.prodId == obj.prodId); and check if theCart has items.

Comment: i want to delete that product from the cart that was the whole idea, how to do it?

Comment: even more, when i comment the attach() and uncomment remove() its says The object cannot be deleted because it was not found in the ObjectStateManager